# Как добавить свой класс ТОЛЬКО к одному элементу меню в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
<ul class="menu_box clearfix">
<li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Beginners</a></li>
<li class="menu_item menu_drop">
    <a href="#" class="menu_link icon_drop">All projects</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Bookmakers</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Forex</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Bux for earnings</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Casino online</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Earnings on advertising</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Exchange crypto currency</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">High-interest HYIP</a></li>
        <li class="sub_item"><a href="#" class="sub_link">Mlm Games</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">About me</a></li>
<li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Refbank</a></li>
```

В этой HTML разметки есть элемент меню с ссылкой, у которой уникальный класс `icon_drop`.

Я добавляю класс с помощью:

```
   add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'nav_css_filter' );
function nav_css_filter( $classes ){
    $classes['class'] = 'icon_drop';
    return $classes;
}
```

Но он добавляет ко всем пунктам меню. А как добавить только к одному?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вверху в админке wordpress есть кнопка(если админка на английском) "screen options", там кнопка Css Classes

Answer (score -2):

Если нужно программно, то можете попробовать так:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'change_menu_item_css_classes', 10, 4 );

function change_menu_item_css_classes( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    if( $item->ID == 265 && $args->theme_location == 'primary' ){
        $classes[] = 'icon_drop';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Вместо $item->ID == 265 можно использовать, например, $item->title == 'All projects', если необходимо.